# php mysql docker exception ssl

Tags: mysql, symfony, pdo, docker, composer-php

I'm trying to transfere our current website that use symfony2 in a docker container.
The developpers that made the deployement script are gone from the company and i never developped with php.

When i build my image i'm running the same command as they use to deploy.

```
php5 -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar self-update && php5 -d memory_limit=-1  composer.phar install --prefer-dist --no-interaction
```

But when it does work at every deployement it failed a building.

- I've checked that my docker image got internet. it does.
- I've copied configuration file and ssl from our production service.
- The installed packaged are: nodejs php5-cli curl php5-curl php5-mcrypt php5-intl php5-gd mcrypt npm php5-gd php5-common php5-mysql
- I use a tool from php-docker to install pdo_mysql: docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

The error when building.

```
PHP Warning:  PDO::__construct(): Cannot connect to MySQL by using SSL in /app/jolicone/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 3863
PHP Warning:  PDO::__construct(): [2002]  (trying to connect via tcp://cleardb.com:port-cleardb) in /app/jolicone/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 3863

  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception

  [RuntimeException]
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...

The command '/bin/sh -c cd /app/jolicone && php5 -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar self-update && php5 -d memory_limit=-1  composer.phar install --prefer-dist --no-interaction' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Does someone have an idea about where that could come frome ? i've trying install another package php5-mysqlnd but this doesn't work either.

If you want a have an eye to the DockerFile

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y apt-utils nodejs php5-cli curl php5-curl php5-mcrypt php5-intl php5-gd mcrypt npm php5-gd php5-common php5-mysqlnd

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql


# Linking nodejs binary to node alias
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/sbin/node


# Telling php about mcrypt extension
RUN sed -i '/memory_limit/c\memory_limit = -1' /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
RUN php5enmod gd mcrypt mysql pdo_mysql

COPY apache2/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
# Local Repository
RUN mkdir /app/
COPY jolicone/ /app/jolicone

############# Installing Composer #################
RUN cd /app/jolicone/ && php5 -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
RUN cd /app\/jolicone && php5 composer-setup.php
RUN cd /app/jolicone && php5 -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

# Copy Apache2 Configuration
COPY apache2/sites-enabled /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
COPY apache2/file.pem apache2/file.crt apache2/file.key /etc/apache2/
COPY apache2/ssl /etc/apache2/ssl
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers && service apache2 restart
#Copy composer.json
RUN rm -f /app/jolicone/composer.json
COPY app/composer.json /app/jolicone/

# Copy config.yml
RUN rm -f /app/jolicone/app/config/config.yml
COPY app/config.yml /app/jolicone/app/config/config.yml

# Copy parameters.yml
RUN rm -f /app/jolicone/app/config/parameters.yml
COPY app/parameters.yml /app/jolicone/app/config/parameters.yml

## mise a jour du composer.phar -> OK
RUN cd /app/jolicone && php5 -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar self-update && php5 -d memory_limit=-1  composer.phar install --prefer-dist --no-interaction
```

Answer (score 0):

So i added the `ca-certificates` packages. and now the build is ok.

But when I run my image and try to connect to the website I got the same error.

```
vmtest:~/Docker$ cat log/*
- - [21/Jun/2016:10:29:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 261 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"
[Tue Jun 21 10:29:04.011586 2016] [:error] [pid 6] [client] PHP Warning:  PDO::__construct(): Cannot connect to MySQL by using SSL in /path/file.php on line 1691
[Tue Jun 21 10:29:04.011648 2016] [:error] [pid 6] [client] PHP Warning:  PDO::__construct(): [2002]  (trying to connect via tcp://db:port) in /path/file.php on line 1691
[Tue Jun 21 10:29:04.011886 2016] [:error] [pid 6] [client] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] ' in /path/file.php:1691\nStack trace:\n#0 /path/file.php(1691): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=db...', '', '', Array)\n#1 /path/bootstrap.php.cache(2051): appProdProjectContainer->getPdoService()\n#2 /path/file.php(1891): Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container->get('pdo')\n#3 /path/bootstrap.php.cache(2051): appProdProjectContainer->getSession_Handler_PdoService()\n#4 /path/file.php(1903): Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container->get('session.handler...')\n#5 /path/bootstrap.php.cache(2051): appProdProjectContainer->getSession_Storage_NativeService()\n#6 /path/file.php(1887): Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container->get('session.storage...')\n#7 /app/jol in /path/file.php on line 1691
vmtest:~/Docker$
```